# Convert raw 264 files to mp4 has no sound

Tags: video

I am trying to convert raw .264 files to mp4 but I am not getting any sound. I am using the command

`ffmpeg -i testinput.264 -c:v copy output.mp4`

and I can see the video file but there is no sound. Are there any other ways to convert raw 264 files to video?

Answer (score 0):

Raw .264 files do not have sound (only video). If the input has no sound, the output will have no sound.